# PyTorch & skorch: How to fix my nn.Module to work with skorch's GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, grid-search, skorch

Using PyTorch, I have an ANN model (for a classification task) below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Setting up artifical neural net model which separates out categorical 
# from continuous features, so that embedding could be applied to 
# categorical features
class TabularModel(nn.Module):
    # Initialize parameters embeds, emb_drop, bn_cont and layers
    def __init__(self, emb_szs, n_cont, out_sz, layers, p=0.5):
        super().__init__()
        self.embeds = nn.ModuleList([nn.Embedding(ni, nf) for ni, nf in emb_szs])
        self.emb_drop = nn.Dropout(p)
        self.bn_cont = nn.BatchNorm1d(n_cont)
        
        # Create empty list for each layer in the neural net
        layerlist = []
        # Number of all embedded columns for categorical features 
        n_emb = sum((nf for ni, nf in emb_szs))
        # Number of inputs for each layer 
        n_in = n_emb + n_cont
        
        for i in layers:
            # Set the linear function for the weights and biases, wX + b
            layerlist.append(nn.Linear(n_in, i)) 
            # Using ReLu activation function
            layerlist.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))   
            # Normalised all the activation function output values
            layerlist.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(i))   
            # Set some of the normalised activation function output values to zero
            layerlist.append(nn.Dropout(p))
            # Reassign number of inputs for the next layer
            n_in = i
        # Append last layer
        layerlist.append(nn.Linear(layers[-1], out_sz))          
        # Create sequential layers
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(*layerlist)
    
    # Function for feedforward
    def forward(self, x_cat_cont):
        x_cat = x_cat_cont[:,0:cat_train.shape[1]].type(torch.int64)
        x_cont = x_cat_cont[:,cat_train.shape[1]:].type(torch.float32)

        # Create empty list for embedded categorical features
        embeddings = []
        # Embed categorical features
        for i, e in enumerate(self.embeds):
            embeddings.append(e(x_cat[:,i]))
        # Concatenate embedded categorical features
        x = torch.cat(embeddings, 1)
        # Apply dropout rates to categorical features
        x = self.emb_drop(x)
        
        # Batch normalize continuous features
        x_cont = self.bn_cont(x_cont)
        
        # Concatenate categorical and continuous features
        x = torch.cat([x, x_cont], 1)
        
        # Feed categorical and continuous features into neural net layers
        x = self.layers(x)
        return x
```

I am trying to use this model with skorch's GridSearchCV, as below:

```
from skorch import NeuralNetBinaryClassifier

# Random seed chosen to ensure results are reproducible by using the same 
# initial random weights and biases, and applying dropout rates to the same 
# random embedded categorical features and neurons in the hidden layers
torch.manual_seed(0)

net = NeuralNetBinaryClassifier(module=TabularModel,
                                module__emb_szs=emb_szs,
                                module__n_cont=con_train.shape[1],
                                module__out_sz=2,
                                module__layers=[30],
                                module__p=0.0,
                                criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss,
                                criterion__weight=cls_wgt,
                                optimizer=torch.optim.Adam,
                                optimizer__lr=0.001,
                                max_epochs=150,
                                device='cuda'
                                )

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {'module__layers': [[30], [50,20]],
              'module__p': [0.0, 0.2, 0.4],
              'max_epochs': [150, 175, 200, 225]
             }

models = GridSearchCV(net, param_grid, scoring='roc_auc').fit(cat_con_train.cpu(), y_train.cpu())

models.best_params_
```

But when I ran the code, I am getting this error message below:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: Expected module output to have shape (n,) or (n, 1), got (128, 2) instead

  FitFailedWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: Expected module output to have shape (n,) or (n, 1), got (128, 2) instead

  FitFailedWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: Expected module output to have shape (n,) or (n, 1), got (128, 2) instead

  FitFailedWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: Expected module output to have shape (n,) or (n, 1), got (128, 2) instead

  FitFailedWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: Expected module output to have shape (n,) or (n, 1), got (128, 2) instead

  FitFailedWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-c408d65e2435> in <module>()
     98 
---> 99 models = GridSearchCV(net, param_grid, scoring='roc_auc').fit(cat_con_train.cpu(), y_train.cpu())
    100 
    101 models.best_params_

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skorch/classifier.py in infer(self, x, **fit_params)
    303             raise ValueError(
    304                 "Expected module output to have shape (n,) or "
--> 305                 "(n, 1), got {} instead".format(tuple(y_infer.shape)))
    306 
    307         y_infer = y_infer.reshape(-1)

ValueError: Expected module output to have shape (n,) or (n, 1), got (128, 2) instead
```

I am not sure what is wrong or how to fix this. Any help on this would really be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There seem to be something wrong with the shape of y_train. I'm unable to reproduce your error with the code you provided, please give the value of cat_con_train and y_train at least.

Comment: Thanks @VincentAgnes. I posted the same question in PyTorch forum and found out it's actually the module used. Please see here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-fix-my-nn-module-to-work-with-skorchs-gridsearchcv/99310

Answer (score 0):

To quote [ptrblck on the pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-fix-my-nn-module-to-work-with-skorchs-gridsearchcv/99310/2) who outlined the solution already:

> I guess the NeuralNetBinaryClassifier expects the output to have one logit, since it’s used for a binary use case.
> If you want to use two output units for a binary classification (which would be a multi-class classification with 2 classes), you would have to use another wrapper I guess.
> I’m not deeply familiar with skorch, but think that NeuralNetClassifier might work.

His assesment was correct. skorch's `NeuralNetBinaryClassifier` expects the `y` to have one dimension, so a shape of `(x, 1)` or `(x,)` where the value of `y` is either 0 or 1. So a valid `y` would be:

```
y = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0]) # shape is (3,)
y = torch.tensor([[0],[1],[0]) # shape is (3, 1)
```